# Semi-empirical software for bands calculations

Tags: software, band-structure, one-topic-per-answer, semi-empirical-method

In Semiconductor Physics, one of the main parameters of interest is the band gap. It is known that, in DFT, there are functionals that underestimate it.

I came across the [MOPAC](http://openmopac.net/) program, a semi-empirical quantum chemistry program based on Dewar and Thiel's NDDO approximation, that have two utilities to work with periodical system.

The picture bellow shows the bands calculated for $\ce{TiO2}$:
[image]

The problem is that, as MOPAC is not for periodic systems, it is a little difficult to calculate the bands with it (it is mandatory to leave the calculations windows open and you can not move the mouse). But, the gap was in agreement with the experimental value :).

Is there any other software with semiempirical methods available to calculate the electronic structure of periodical systems?

Comment: I believe you want to look into DFTB methods, which would be the equivalent of semiempirical molecular methods. I see [Ti-oxide parameters](https://www.dftb.org/parameters/download/tiorg/tiorg-0-1-cc/) at DFTB.org

Comment: My experience with MOPAC is good for molecules, but it's a pain for periodic systems because the unit cell has to be a certain size (e.g., you usually have to generate a supercell).

Comment: @GeoffHutchison Different implementations of DFTB are indeed very helpful (and fast) to produce band structures and DOS. However, both the method and the parameterization is derived from DFT, therefore it inherits the biases of DFT.

Answer (score 8):

## DFTB+

One option is DFTB+. It is free, open source, has been around for more than a couple years now, and has a fairly big community.

You are also very lucky, since your question is about the band structure of TiO$_2$ and the [sample input](https://dftbplus-recipes.readthedocs.io/en/stable/basics/bandstruct.html) that DFTB+ provides for band structure calculations is for... TiO$_2$ :)

The following might also be useful:

- [DFTB+ documentation](https://dftbplus-recipes.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html).
- [DFTB+ GitHub Organization](https://github.com/dftbplus) (includes links to the Git repositories for the  DFTB+ software, documentation, developer guide, and many other things).
- [DFTB+ website](http://www.dftbplus.org/) (includes a [list of features](http://www.dftbplus.org/about-dftb/features/), [pages for previous versions](http://www.dftbplus.org/download/deprecated/), and [ways to contact the community](http://www.dftbplus.org/contact-support/)).
- [Recent paper in the 2020 JCP Special Issue on software](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.5143190).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108746/discussion-on-answer-by-nike-dattani-semi-empirical-software-for-bands-calculati).