# Software to draw 3d micelle configuration

Tags: software, from-chem-se, visualization-software

I am looking for a free software able to draw 3d micelle configuration like the figure attached.

Any suggestion?

[image]

Comment: I think [Packmol](http://m3g.iqm.unicamp.br/packmol/home.shtml) might be what you're looking for.

Comment: You're welcome. [GROMACS](http://manual.gromacs.org/documentation/2019/how-to/visualize.html) can do micelle simulations, but maybe the visualization is done in VMD? Can you please tell us where this diagram came from? I might like to ask the authors how these specific figures were generated.

Comment: @FelipeS.S.Schneider I use packmol to create initial configurations of my Lammps simulations (software that i use to do my molecular simulations). I agree with you that with Packmol i could do that. With packmol, I would have to create the system and, after that, post processing in a software like vmd. However, what I'm looking for is something simple, a freeware software able to draw 3d structures like the observed ones in this kind of system (i just wanna draw something didatic, without much detail).

Comment: @NikeDattani I use Lammps to do my molecular simulations. I agree with you that Lammps (or Gromacs) i could obtain this kind of struture and, after that, i would have to post processing the results to obtain a image like that in a software like vmd. However, what I'm looking for is something simple, a software able to draw 3d structures like the observed ones in this kind of system (i just wanna draw something didatic, without much detail). I am looking for suggestions of free material engineering softwares that could perform this task.

Comment: @NikeDattani This figure was obtained from an article published in 2007 (https://doi.org/10.1016/j.progpolymsci.2007.05.004). I sent an email to the author, but given the time of publication I don't have much hope for the answer (given previous personal experiences too). In addition, this figure seems to be obtained in some paid software (i feel that). What I'm looking for is freeware software, since I'm a student and my budget is limited :)

Comment: I found that Rhino3d is able to draw this kind of structure (i was refuted and the author fast reply me). I will refresh my question with this software suggestion, however, i will let my question open if someone else would like to give any other suggestion.

Comment: @EmersonPL Excellent! In any case, you could add an answer to your own question, so that the solution you found can be shared with others.

Answer (score 9):

I found some software that can do this kind of work:

- Rhino3d
- 3ds Max

Comment: I'm very glad you found the answer, and I thank you for sharing it with us so that the next person might benefit from your answer. I wonder if it might be possible for you to elaborate on your answer a bit? For this software recommendation question, I suggested a software and wrote the advantages and disadvantages: https://materials.stackexchange.com/a/1324/5. In this one I gave links to some of the important sites related to the software (main website, documentation site, GitHub repository, etc): https://materials.stackexchange.com/a/1152/5. In other questions people say whether it's free etc